# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac. A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

Tags: java, glassfish

When I deploy a war file of my web project in Glassfish, I am getting the following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a full JDK (Java SDK) including javac compiler tool on the glassfish server machine and executable path should be correctly set. This is required for compiling JSP files to java class files on the fly.

EDIT: Other option could be precompile your JSP files and package the compiled class output in the WAR file. You can google on how to precompile JSPs using a build tool like Apache ANT.